# Count how many times value A exists in dataframe rows, how many times value B and how many times value A and B

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, count, csv

I have a dataframe "dfTags" with 140.000 rows (all lowercase), number of comma separated values in column "tags" can range from 71 to 1. But column tags is one single string, Pandas does not know arrays or lists:

```
index tags
0     a, b, c, aa, bb, 2019
1     a, d, 18, gb
2     aa, a, dd, fb, la
3     aa, d, ddaa, b, k, l
```

and a set "tagTuples" containing 850.000 sorted tuples (all lowercase) build from the tags in each row like:

```
(a, b), (b, c), (aa, c), (aa, bb), (2019, bb), (a, d), (18, d), (18, gb), (a, aa), (a, dd), (dd, fb), (fb, la), (aa, d), (d, ddaa), ...
```

I used a set because I removed every tag that occurs only once and then just added every created tuple, automatically removing duplicates.

For every tuple in "tagTuples" I need:

- e.g. (a, b)
- how many rows in column "tags" contain "a"? (3)
- how many rows in column "tags" that contain "a" also contain "b"? (1)
- = 1/3 => 0,33
- how many rows in column "tags" contain "b"? (2)
- how many rows in column "tags" that contain "b" also contain "a"? (1)
- = 1/2 => 0,5

  resulting in an edge weight between a<>b = (0,33 + 0,5)*100 = 83% (modified Jaccard index)

each result should than be pushed into a dataframe dfTagTuple

```
dfTagTuple = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Source", "Target", "Weight"])
```

where Source = tuple[0], Target = tuple[1], Weight = Edge Weight

so that I get Edge connections between each tag with the edge weight to visualize them in Gephi, creating a tag network.

But the tags are of type "object" because Pandas doesn't know arrays. So how can I check each tuple for that formula without counting "aa"/"ddaa"/"la" when I check if row["tags"] contains "a"?

And how can I perform those 4 checks and getting the endresult (0,833..) per tuple in a performant way?

```
def calc_distance(tagLeft, tagRight):
# how many times does "a" appear in tags per row?
onlyTagLeft = ??
# # how many times does "b" appear in tags per row?
onlyTagRight = ??
# how many times does "a" and "b" appear together in tags per row?
bothTags = ??
edgeWeight = ((bothTags / onlyTagLeft) + (bothTags / onlyTagRight)) * 100
# print(tagLeft, "#", tagRight, edgeWeight)
print("{}: {}, {}: {}, bothTags: {}, weight: {}".format(tagLeft, onlyTagLeft, tagRight, onlyTagRight, bothTags,
                                                        edgeWeight))

df = pd.DataFrame([["a, b, c, aa, bb, 2019"], ["a, d, 18, gb"], ["aa, a, dd, fb, la"], ["aa, d, ddaa, b, k, l"]], columns=["tags"])
tagSet = {('aa', 'd'), ('a', 'aa'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'b')}

for tagTuple in tagSet:
calc_distance(tagTuple[0], tagTuple[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it will give you, for every tagTupples(`tt`) how many times the first element of the `tt` appears and how many times both of them appear and then you can do your calculations

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'tags': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa'], ['a', 'd'], ['aa', 'a', 'dd']]})
tt = [('a', 'b'), ('aa', 'c')]

for t in tt:
    el_1 = t[0]
    el_2 = t[1]
    only_el_1 = df.tags.apply(lambda x: el_1 in x).sum()
    both_el = df.tags.apply(lambda x: (el_1 in x) and (el_2 in x)).sum()

    print("First element of tupple {} is contained {} times and the both elements are contained {} times".format(t,
                                                                                                                 only_el_1,
                                                                                                                 both_el))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Column "tags" is a single string, Pandas does not know lists or arrays. Counting "a" also counts "aa" in your case. Expanded my question to eliminate uncertainty.